# Road detection from an image by Sobel and Hough Transform

Tags: matlab, image-processing, signal-processing, hough-transform, sobel

I have done Sobel and Hough transform but I can not find the actual result. I have shared my code and corresponding output. The final output is not satisfactory. I need 3 lines; both the road lines and the lane line also (in the middle).

**Input Image**

[image: input image]

**Detect Lines**

[image]

```
clear all
clc
I=imread('22roi.jpg');
%I = imdilate(I,strel('disk',1));
[ga] = RGBThreshold(I,[175 175 175]);
gg = imdilate(ga,strel('disk',1));
gg=imfill(gg,'holes');
c=edge(gg,'sobel');%sobel
figure,imshow(gg);
%figure,imshow(c);
[H,T,R]=hough(c);
figure,imshow(H,[],'XData',T,'YData',R,'InitialMagnification','fit');
xlabel('\theta'),ylabel('\rho');
axis on,axis normal,hold on;
P=houghpeaks(H,5,'threshold',ceil(0.3*max(H(:))));
x=T(P(:,2));y=R(P(:,1));
plot(x,y,'s','color','white');
% houghlines
lines=houghlines(c,T,R,P,'FillGap',10,'MinLength',7);
%figure,imshow(I);
figure,imshow(c),hold on;
max_len = 0;
for k = 1:length(lines)
    xy = [lines(k).point1; lines(k).point2];
    plot(xy(:,1),xy(:,2),'LineWidth',2,'Color','green');
    % Plot beginnings and ends of lines
    plot(xy(1,1),xy(1,2),'x','LineWidth',2,'Color','red');
    plot(xy(2,1),xy(2,2),'x','LineWidth',2,'Color','green');
    % Determine the endpoints of the longest line segment
    len = norm(lines(k).point1 - lines(k).point2);
    if ( len > max_len)
        max_len = len;
        xy_long = xy;
    end
end
% highlight the longest line segment
plot(xy_long(:,1),xy_long(:,2),'LineWidth',2,'Color','green');
% figure,imshow(I);
figure,  hold on;
max_len=0;
for k=1:6
    xy=[lines(k).point1;lines(k).point2];
    %figure,imshow(I);
    plot(xy(:,1,:),-xy(:,2),'LineWidth',3,'color','green');     
end
```

Comment: Please post runnable code. Somehow, `[` is (wrongly) escaped with `\[`.

Comment: corrected now.....sorry